# Initialize contract method on frontend and complete on server

Tags: web3js, contract-design, dapp-development

I am creating a Dapp and using metamask. I want to approve the transaction cost on the front end using meta mask, from there I want to send the transaction hash to the backend and complete the transaction there. Is this possible to do with a contract method? I know its possible to do for a transaction like this:

Front-end:

```
const { raw } = await web3.eth.signTransaction({ ... });
```

Back-end:

```
web3.eth.sendSignTransaction(raw)
```

Is this possible to do with a contract method? I want to approve the gas transaction fee from the front-end.

Can I do it using `myContract.methods.myMethod(123).encodeABI();` on the front end? And then send the ABI to `web3.eth.signTransaction()`?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this possible to do with a contract method? I want to approve the gas transaction fee from the front-end.

Yes it's possible. As you already suggested: `myContract.methods.myMethod(123).encodeABI()` is the way to go. You need to put the output of this call to `{..., data: ..., ...}` of the transaction, then sign it.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of.

You can make a smart contract respect only the server (and the server pays for gas).

`modifier onlyServer {
  require(msg.sender == serverAddress);
  _;
}`

Great.

To really find out what a transaction will cost, it will need to be checked on the server side. You can "dry run" it with `.call()` to get a gas price, or use the `web3.eth.estimateGas` method.

You can also require that the server present evidence (to the contract) that the user signed a transaction. So, the server says "I have a message signed by Alice" and the contract checks before doing anything to its records about Alice. This is roughly how 0x works, so their whitepaper might give you some ideas.

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish and where you want the authority and the gas fees to land, the suggested flow might not be ideal. Ethereum often changes the flow in unexpected ways.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For my use case I want to sign the transaction on the client and send it to the server so the client pays for gas. In web3 1.0 beta there is a signTransaction method which would work perfect however it is not implemented in meta mask yet. So my options are roll my own solution which would require handling private keys (dont want to do that) or wait for meta mask to implement this. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you sure the flow needs go from the client to the server? There may be (usually is) another way to architect the solution.

Comment: You're right. I am using the `encodeAbi` method on the server and send the abi back in the response and execute the transaction from the client.