# Binance network: secure transaction verification

Tags: solidity, dapps, binance

I have a BEP-20 token deployed under Binance Smart Chain.

I'm also trying to implement a web3 dapp that will send tokens from one address to another one and I need to verify this transaction on the backend.

1. Should I write a separate contract to perform communication between BEP-20 token and call initiate transfer from there and do validation on its side? Can I actually call deployed contract function from another contract (I couldn't find a recipe how to do that)?
2. If I will send a token from the frontend, can I verify the user's transaction on the backend? If so, how? I tried this [approach](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44578/initialize-contract-method-on-frontend-and-complete-on-server) but it doesn't work for me. It shows "RPC method is not supported" in the browser console. (I'm using injected web3)